# arcore/sceneform load webview in augmented reality

Tags: java, android, webview, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying to create an app which load a webview using arcore. When the camera of the device focus a specify image, the app should to show a webview like google.com inside the image.

I've created a viewRenderable which load the layout with the webView, but when I focus the image, the webview shows white page:

onCreate method:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_web_image, null);

    WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView_sycket);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

Method which create the viewRenderable

```
ViewRenderable.builder()
                .setView(this, R.layout.view_web_image)
                .setVerticalAlignment(ViewRenderable.VerticalAlignment.CENTER)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(viewRenderable -> placeView(viewRenderable, image));
```

Method which fit the webview according to the image's size focused by the camera

```
private void placeView(ViewRenderable viewRenderable, AugmentedImage image) {

    Float imageWidth = 0.20f;
    Float imageHeight = 0.11f;

    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode();

    anchorNode.setAnchor(image.createAnchor(image.getCenterPose()));

    Float arWidth = image.getExtentX();
    Float arHeight = image.getExtentZ();

    Float scaledWidth = imageWidth / arWidth;
    Float scaledHeight = imageHeight / arHeight;

    Node viewImage = new Node();
    viewImage.setLocalScale(new Vector3(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, imageWidth));

    viewImage.setLocalRotation(new Quaternion(new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f), -90f));

    viewImage.setRenderable(viewRenderable);

    viewImage.setParent(anchorNode);

    arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);

}
```